# Can't access $_SESSION variable in PHP called from Flash

Tags: php, jquery, flash

I'm having difficulty accessing a `$_SESSION` variable.

I have `session_start()` at the beginning of the file.

I'm using jQuery uploadify and it calls a php backend file, which can't access `$_SESSION` variables, although other files outside could.

Could it have something to do with the way that flash (jquery uploadify) is calling the php?

Does anyone know how to circumvent this?

UPDATE: included session_id in the url but it didnt work.

```
$('#image_upload').uploadify({
    'uploader':     '../../frontend/jquery/plugins/uploadify/swf/uploadify.swf',
    'script':       "controllers/image_upload.php?SID='.session_id()'",
    'fileDataName': 'upload',
    'method':       'POST',
    'multi':        'true',
    'fileDesc':     'tseting',
    'fileExt':      '*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.png',
    'sizeLimit':    '100000000',
    'buttonText':   'Ladda upp bilder',
    'auto':         'true'
});
```

EDIT: i think i know what the problem is.

in the header information with livehtmlheader in FF it shows an error message:

```
 HTTP/1.x 404 Not Found
```

while the other regular page requests shows

```
 HTTP/1.x 200 OK
```

someone knows how to solve this?

EDIT: sorry i've had wrong. it was not cause by 404, that was a request to another file. there is NO request when posting with uploadify! no html header is sent. i think it uses another approach to get the php file with flash (uploadify.swf).

so there is no way of sending that sessid to my php file now i guess:( have to find some other way around

Comment: "Can't access" is somewhat vague. What's the error/notice message?

Comment: Use LiveHTTPHeaders to inspect the HTTP request jQuery is sending.  Is it including the PHPSESSID cookie?

Comment: Your XMLHTTPRequests are probably missing the session ID. Either in the URL or in a cookie.

Comment: @frank farmer: could you give me some more detail, where and what to type?

Comment: How do you carry the session ID along? In the URL or with a cookie?

Comment: dont understand the problem. the session_id cookie is there. and its on the same machine. and i also tried to send it by post. but it didnt work. so what could the problem be?

Comment: its by the cookie, cause when you use session_start() it creates a session id cookie. it's just when uploadify requests the php file it cant read it. i think it has something to do with flash cause uploadify uses it to enable multiple file uploads.

Comment: @franke: i've installed livehttpheaders and looked at the header, all page requests including jquery's request sends along phpsessid cookie.  its the same id for all. weird...what could the problem be?

Comment: please read my updated question

Comment: You are missing the PHP opener and closer: `<?` and `?>` when outputting session_id().

Comment: but that still wont work cause thats in the javascript. i have to do that in the server side.

Comment: By default the session id url parameter is called `PHPSESSID`, so maybe that's why `SID` is not working for you. (unless you changed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.uploadify.com/forums/discussion/606/io-error-php-session/p1

Answer (score 2):

In certain browsers (firefox iirc) "special" calls, such as file uploads and amf do not always send along the session cookie. The most practical way to sidestep this is to set it as a flashvar when embedding the flash and manually send it along with your request.

Comment: don´t quite understand your solution. is it easy to implement and are there any tutorials?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding manually "?SID=".session_id() to the URL.

Comment: JavaScript is doing the request, not PHP. So `session_id` is not available.

Comment: OP, you are missing opening and closing PHP tags in your implementation of Artjom's hint: `<? ?>`